# Подёргивание "слоёв" при реализации parallax

Tags: javascript, parallax

Пытаюсь реализовать самостоятельно parallax-эффект. Да, понимаю, что существуют уже готовые решения, но вот в целях саморазвития решил написать сие дело с нуля и на "голом" js (без jq). Так вот, столкнулся с проблемой, что "слои", которые я обрабатываю через js, подёргиваются, причём только при прокрутке колесом. При ручной прокрутке скроллбара - всё ОК. Обновляю слои следующим образом:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    requestAnimFrame(scrollCalc);
}

scrollCalc = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < parallaxes.length; i++) {
        var offset = (parallaxParents[i].getBoundingClientRect().top) * (-1) * parallaxes[i].magnitude;
        parallaxes[i].style.transform = "translate3d(0, " + offset + "px, 0)";
    }
}

requestAnimFrame = (
    window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
);
```

в parallaxParents хранятся родительские dom элементы слоёв-параллаксов, а в parallaxes - собственно, эти самые слои.

PS: дёргает на chrome, а в firefox заметил микрофризы. Полагаю, что первопричина этих двух нюансов может крыться в одной и той же проблеме.

Comment: У меня была похожая проблема, когда я делал эффект фонарика. Жутко лагало в хроме, подлагивало в мозиле, и, как ни странно, летало на IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спросил, сам решил =)
Решение я написал на английском stack overflow-е.

[Smooth parallax effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360276/smooth-parallax-effect/)